# Delete batch operation in Azure Storage

Tags: java, azure-table-storage

I have been trying to implement a DAO method for delete operation for Azure Storage entities. Delete using TableOperation was ok.

```
TableOperation deleteEntity = TableOperation.delete(entity);
```

But when I tried it using Batch Operation, It was not supported.

Any suggestions to overcome this issue is highly appreciated.

Comment: What error were you hitting when you tried to delete entities in batch? Please note that the entities in a batch should share the same partition key.

Comment: The error was `code` java.lang.ClassCastException. Yes I was using the same partition key

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But when I tried it using Batch Operation, It was not supported.

I assumed that you could group your items for deleting by partition key, then execute the `TableBatchOperation`.

Here I wrote a helper class via C# language for achieving this purpose, you could refer to it:

```
public class TableBatchHelper<T> where T : ITableEntity
{
    const int batchMaxSize = 100;

    public static IEnumerable<TableBatchOperation> GetBatchesForDelete(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var list = new List<TableBatchOperation>();
        var partitionGroups = items.GroupBy(arg => arg.PartitionKey).ToArray();
        foreach (var group in partitionGroups)
        {
            T[] groupList = group.ToArray();
            int offSet = batchMaxSize;
            T[] entities = groupList.Take(offSet).ToArray();
            while (entities.Any())
            {
                var tableBatchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
                foreach (var entity in entities)
                {
                    tableBatchOperation.Add(TableOperation.Delete(entity));
                }
                list.Add(tableBatchOperation);
                entities = groupList.Skip(offSet).Take(batchMaxSize).ToArray();
                offSet += batchMaxSize;
            }
        }
        return list;
    }

    public static async Task BatchDeleteAsync(CloudTable table, IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        var batches = GetBatchesForDelete(items);
        await Task.WhenAll(batches.Select(table.ExecuteBatchAsync));
    }
}
```

Then, you could you execute the batch deleting as follows:

```
await TableBatchHelper<ClassName>.BatchDeleteAsync(cloudTable,items);
```

Or

```
var batches = TableBatchHelper<ClassName>.GetBatchesForDelete(entities);
Parallel.ForEach(batches, new ParallelOptions()
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 5
}, (batchOperation) =>
    {
        try
        {
            table.ExecuteBatch(batchOperation);
            Console.WriteLine("Writing {0} records", batchOperation.Count);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ExecuteBatch throw a exception:" + ex.Message);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Yes I was able to  group items for deleting by partition key. I tried it using your example. But still gives an error saying  java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to com.microsoft.azure.storage.table.TableOperation
 at com.aepona.iotp.azure.reporting.AzureIotLocationDataDao.deleteLocationsForDevice(AzureIotLocationDataDao.java:188)

Comment: Do your code write in java? My code snippet was written by C#. The error is about type conversion exception, you could try your best to fix this error, or you could update your question with your code snippet for us to locate the error.

Answer (score 1):

No, That was the code without using block operation. Following is the code that includes block operation. Sorry for not mentioning that

```
 TableBatchOperation batchOperation = new TableBatchOperation();
    List<TableBatchOperation> list = new ArrayList<>();

    if (partitionQuery != null) {
        for (AzureLocationData entity : cloudTable.execute(partitionQuery)) {

            batchOperation.add(TableOperation.delete(entity));
            list.add(batchOperation);    //exception thrown line
        }
        try {
            cloudTable.execute((TableOperation) batchOperation);
        } catch (StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            }
            }
```

Comment: From [CloudTable](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/CloudTable.html), we could find it supports `CloudTable.execute(TableBatchOperation batch)`, you need to change your code for executing batch operation like this `cloudTable.execute(batchOperation);`.

Comment: Additionally, a single [TableBatchOperation](https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk-for-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/table/TableBatchOperation.html) could contain up to 100 individual table operations, you could add multiple table operations into a single TableBatchOperation instance, then iterate the `List<TableBatchOperation>` and invoke the `CloudTable.execute(TableBatchOperation batch)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void deleteLocationsForDevice(String id) {
    logger.info("Going to delete location data for Device [{}]", id);

    // Create a filter condition where the partition key is deviceId.
    String partitionFilter = TableQuery.generateFilterCondition(
            PARTITION_KEY,
            TableQuery.QueryComparisons.EQUAL,
            id);

    // Specify a partition query, using  partition key filter.
    TableQuery<AzureLocationData> partitionQuery =
            TableQuery.from(AzureLocationData.class)
                    .where(partitionFilter);



    if (partitionQuery != null) {
        for (AzureLocationData entity : cloudTable.execute(partitionQuery)) {

            TableOperation deleteEntity = TableOperation.delete(entity);
            try {
                cloudTable.execute(deleteEntity);
                logger.info("Successfully deleted location records with : " + entity.getPartitionKey());
            } catch (StorageException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    } else {
        logger.debug("No records to delete!");
    }

    //  throw new UnsupportedOperationException("AzureIotLocationDataDao Delete Operation not supported");
}
```

Comment: `ClassCastException` was thrown by the above method? Could you locate the specific code line?